# How to make build for react app for different stages?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, web-deployment

I have a single page application which is a react app. I am using webpack for it. I am facing problem in configuring server API URL for every stage like test, beta and prod.

Is there some standard way of doing it?

Answer (score 1):

Create a `.env` and add your variables there ensuring that they are prefixed with `REACT_APP` e.g. `REACT_APP_SERVER_URL=https://example.com`

You can create multiple env files one each for dev, prod, test etc. like `.env.local`, `.env.prod`

The env files injected from your npm commands

```
npm start: .env.development.local, .env.development, .env.local, .env
npm run build: .env.production.local, .env.production, .env.local, .env
```

Use the variable in your code like

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
    analytics.disable();
 }
```

OR

```
 <b>{process.env.NODE_ENV}</b>
```

Refer https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#adding-development-environment-variables-in-env

Comment: This doesn't allow you to differentiate between, say, beta and prod which are both built with `npm run build` but deployed to different places.

Answer (score 0):

Do that based on `NODE_ENV`.

declare an url file in your application for the basepath of it.

```
const baseURL = (__DEV__) ? url1 : url 2;
```

or a switch statement, does'nt matter.

Do be able to have access to these variables, you have to use [DefinePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/#src/components/Sidebar/Sidebar.jsx) from webpack.

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  envType: JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV)
})
```

or something like that...